# Efficient splitting of delimeter separated messages coming in a stream

Tags: c#, stream

I want a memory-efficient and time-efficient way of splitting up an incoming stream of data based on a delimeter. The stream is a network-stream and the "messages" coming in are split up by `CRLF`. Previously I've done this by converting incomming data to a string using UTF8, then check for CRLF, and if it exists I split based on that, however, that is not a very good way to solve the problem as more and more messages are incoming. Also, I might get data-chunks containing 1 message, and I might get datachunks containing 10 messages, and even some that only contains parts of messages.

So this is what I have thought up so far. Use a memorystream for buffer, and when data comes in read the data into the memory-stream. If I find the delimeter (CRLF), I take all the data in the memorystream, and call the messageReceived on that, then I continue. Any thoughts on this?

**[Edit]**
Ok, I think I need to better explain what  I want to do. The protocoll beeing used is the IRC-protocoll, which sends "messages", or "commands" if you want, sepparated by `CRLF`. I'm using the socket-class in C# with BeginReceive and EndReceive, so everything runs async. The class I'm writing is called a MessageConnection. It receives data from a tcp-socket, and whenever a given delimeter is found (in this case `CRLF`) I want it to call a function called OnMessage witch takes the received message as a parameter. I've solved the exact same problem before using a StringBuilder as a buffer, and appending the new string to the StringBuilder whenever I received data, then I'd split the string returned by the StringBuilder based on the delimeter, empty the StringBuilder, and insert the last part of the split-operation. After that I loop trough the split-array (without the last element) and call OnMessage. This howerver feels like an inefficient way of solving the problem, cause I do a lot of conversion to and from strings - which is said not to be verry good, so I was thinking, there needs to be a simple way to solve this without having to think in strings, just in byte-arrays, and only convert to a string when I have a byte-array that represents an actuall "message", and this is what I want help with.

Comment: I don't suppose you have control over the messaging system?  I only ask because this is a highly unreliable means of communication; almost every major network protocol either uses fixed-size blocks or includes the message size as a field within the message...

Comment: @Alxandr - is your data in any specific format? is it just Strings being transferred over the wire? or are you splitting each message up by a Node tag like you would with XML? A bit more information about the type of stream of data being sent over the wire would be great.

Comment: No, the format is simple. It's "messages" (can be anything, but in this case it's IRC-protocoll) separated by <CRLF>. What I wan't is simply to fire an event (OnMessage) with the message as a parameter (using my own MessageEventArgs) whenever I receive a CRLF.

Comment: Deleted proposed answer after question was reworked.

Comment: since this is "commands" is there a way to normalize the messages to a smaller set (like an enum) so that you are transmitting less data? Or are this messages free form so that text is required? Do you control the message sender and receiver?

Comment: No, I don't controll the sender. And text is required. A typicall command is something like "PRIVMSG #nvg :Here comes the message"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you actually have the right idea.  Just do it with a byte array.

Here's how I'd do it, purely untested, and could be optimized....

```
byte[] m_LongBuffer;
byte[] m_SmallBuffer;
void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult iar)
{
   //m_SmallBuffer contains the data read from the stream
   //Append it to m_LongBuffer
   int bytesread = socket.EndReceive(iar);
   m_LongBuffer = m_LongBuffer.Concat(m_SmallBuffer.Take(bytesread)).ToArray();

   int startpoint = 0;
   int splitpoint = 0;
   int lastendpoint = 0;
   bool twochar = false;

   do
   {
       int i = 0;
       for(i = 0;i < m_LongBuffer.Length; ++i)
       {
           if((m_LongBuffer[i] == 0x0A) || (m_LongBuffer[i] == 0x0D))
           {
               splitpoint = i;
               if((m_LongBuffer[i+1] == 0x0A) || (m_LongBuffer[i+1] == 0x0D))
                    twochar=true;
               else
                    twochar=false;
               
               lastendpoint = splitpoint;                   
               String message = ASCII.ASCIIEncoding.GetString(m_LongBuffer.Skip(startpoint).Take(splitpoint - startpoint).ToArray());
               //Do something with the message
               startpoint = splitpoint + (twochar ? 2 : 1);
               break;
           }
       }
       if(i >= m_LongBuffer.Length)
            splitpoint = -1;
   } while (splitpoint != -1);
   m_LongBuffer = m_LongBuffer.Skip(lastendpoint).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Your `i` in `if(i >= m_LongBuffer.Length)` is out of scope

Comment: I haven't checked but by the look of it, you should initialize your `i` to `startpoint` in your loop. Something like this: `for(i = startpoint;i < m_LongBuffer.Length; ++i)`

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something like this a while back. I solved it by creating a producer/consumer stream. The producer (in your case, the thing that reads the network stream) writes bytes to the stream, and the consumer creates a `StreamReader` connected to the stream.

Granted, this requires another thread for the consumer, but it prevents problems that might occur if the callback takes too long and you end up missing messages.

I wrote up the stream, which I called `ProducerConsumerStream` in an article. See it at http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=852.

A previous solution to the problem involved parsing the byte array myself. That worked, but wasn't as flexible as this stream approach.