# Get last word of string that starts with 5555/ and ends with 0/

Tags: c#, string, extract

I have a string containg double data that is being sent by sockets. Due to network delay I get overloaded data on the client side, meaning my actual string is

> 5555/57.6626/63.364/0/

and I get this string on client side:

> 5555/989.994/262.65645/0/**5555/165.6515/6526.545/0/**

So basically two strings are merged. I want the last updated string that is in bold format.

Note that `5555/` and `/0/` are the delimiters, my actual data is between these delimiters.

Comment: And the data between the delimiters is always a sequence of floating point values, separated by "/"? And none of these values can ever be "5555" or "0"?

Comment: Yup exactly data between /5555 and /0/ can not ever be 5555 and 0.

Comment: This seems like you're using TCP - it's not "network delay" that's causing this, this is how TCP works. It doesn't send (or receive) little packets of data - it works with streams. You need to handle not only receiving multiple "messages" with one Read, but also not receiving the whole message in one Read (or multiple whole messages and one incomplete). TCP even actively batches data within a small time interval by default. Make sure your code can handle all the ways that TCP behaves, or use a network library that gives you messages on top of TCP.

Comment: Exactly so what you suggest how can I handle the data.

Comment: Maybe have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761618/efficient-splitting-of-delimeter-separated-messages-coming-in-a-stream

Comment: If you are using .NET 6: there is a nice helper for handling TCP streams: [Pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "5555/989.994/262.65645/0/5555/165.6515/6526.545/0/";
var x = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf("5555/") + 5).
    Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf("0/") - s.LastIndexOf("5555") - 5);
```

result:

```
165.6515/6526.545/
```

Comment: Actually sir I have some sort of complex problem. Its not the surity that data after 5555 is complete data till delimiter 0. Actually I want the last data of between 5555 and 0, not only the data after last 5555.

Answer (score 0):

another variant

```
var s = "5555/989.994/262.65645/0/5555/165.6515/6526.545/0/";
var x = s.Split("5555/").Last().Split("0/")[0];
```

C# 8.0

```
var x = s.Split("5555/")[^1].Split("0/")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the last occurrence, and given that

> data between /5555 and /0/ can not ever be 5555 and 0

you can use a pattern matching `5555/` and then assert no more occurrences of that part to the right using a negative lookahead `(?!\S*/5555/)`

Then match until `/0/`. As there are no spaces in the example string, you can use `\S*` to match optional non whitespace characters.

```
var input = "5555/989.994/262.65645/0/5555/165.6515/6526.545/0/";
var m = Regex.Match(input, @"5555/(?!\S*/5555/)\S*/0/");
if (m.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Output

```
5555/165.6515/6526.545/0/
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a regular expression:

```
Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<=(^|/)5555/)[\d\./]+?(?=/0(/|$))")
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=(^|/)5555/)` will check for "5555/" at the beginning of the input or after a "/", but not include this in the match
- `[\d\./]+?` will match any sequence of digits, dots and slashes (the `?` is for a non-greedy match, i.e. the shortest match possible)
- `(?=/0(/|$))` will check for "/0" at the end of the input or preceding a "/", but not include this in the match

This will produce two matches "989.994/262.65645" and "165.6515/6526.545"; just take the last one.

Comment: But I just want the last updated string, not the previous one. This means in repetitive strings I want the most last string. What should I do?

Comment: `Regex.Matches(...).Last()`?